# GPS location is enabled but can't find device location

Tags: java, android, android-studio, location

The application is stuck at the white dialogue box, even after enabling the location.
There are two files as mentioned below for location responsibility.

---

1. RemindActivity.java:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remind_activity);
  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
.
.
.
        LocationPremissionCheck();
        GooglePlayServiceCheck();
        GPSLocationServiceCheck();
.
.
.
}
```

```
 private void GPSLocationServiceCheck() {
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, enable it to use this app?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RemindActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

---

The above same thing is written in RemindActivity.java as follows:

2. RemindActivity.java:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.remind_activity);
  locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
.
.
.
        LocationPremissionCheck();
        GooglePlayServiceCheck();
        GPSLocationServiceCheck();
.
.
.
}
```

```
 private void GPSLocationServiceCheck() {
        if (!locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER)) {

            final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setMessage("Your GPS seems to be disabled, enable it to use this app?")
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(RemindActivity.this, StartActivity.class);
                            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(intent);
                            finish();

                        }
                    });
            final AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
            alert.show();
        }
    }
```

[image]

[image]

This a screen for Signup & this location works on some devices but not on all(as I tested).
The application is stuck at the white dialogue box, even after enabling the location.

How to resolve this issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: use service to check continuously about Gps .

Comment: @androidLearner how to do that bro...please guide me

Answer (score 0):

If you are just want to check, location is enabled or not  when app is in foreground ,use below method.

once you launched location source settings close the dialog and show some refresh button in your activity.when you tap on refresh button ,again recreate activity.

```
     public void onClick(@SuppressWarnings("unused") final DialogInterface dialog, @SuppressWarnings("unused") final int id) {
                            startActivity(new Intent(android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS));
                             finish();
                        }

     //in your activity
        public void onRefresh() {
             reCreate();
            }
    }
```